# How do I get a Playground file from GitHub into the iOS Plagrounds app?

Tags: ios, github, swift-playground

Without using macOS at all, is it possible to get a playground file from GitHub into the iOS Playgrounds app?

Comment: Spontaneous idea: Use GitHub on mobile iOS device => download it there => use AirDrop to transfer it to your Playgrounds app. Would that be a viable workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A couple of ways.

The easiest is if the playground is already stored as a zip file on github. For example, there are a few here:

https://github.com/erica/swiftslowly/tree/master/Playground%20Secrets%20and%20Power%20Tips

You can click on the download link for a particular playground and choose copy to playgrounds. If you want to view the contents then use an app that can view zip contents. I use goodreader.

If the playground content you want is just in a swift file on GitHub then you can select the text and copy into a blank playground. The blank playground is available if you click on get playground on the My Playgrounds page and then click Starting Points at the bottom of the page.